# Правильная структура jQuery плагина, с публичными функциями

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин, функции

Для тренировки делаю плагин, открывающий/закрывающий всплывающие окна.
Соответственно в нем должны быть методы: открыть окно, закрыть окно и т.д.
Эти методы должны вызываться, как внутри плагина, при совершении определенных действий, так и извне: `$('#box').plugin.close() или $('#box').plugin('close');`

Я перечитал все мануалы, возможные структуры плагинов.
Сейчас он реализован с помощью стандартной структуры, когда методы `init`, `destroy` выделены в объект `methods`. Но я не понимаю, как правильно реализовать метод `close`.

Я не понимаю, какие параметры ему нужно передавать, или как его вызывать, чтобы он видел переменные определенные в теле функции плагина.

Вот примерная структура:

```
(function( $ ){

       var pop = function(element, options, callback1st, callback2nd)
       {
            var elem = $(element),
                obj = this,
                self = $(this);

            var settings = $.extend({
                openSpeed: '300',
                closeSpeed:'300',
                openAnim: 'default',
                closeAnim: 'default',
                method: 'default',
                checkboxShow: '3',
                callback1st: 'default',
                callback2nd: 'default'
            }, options || {} );

            var mpControl = elem.find(".mpcontrol"),
                mpContent = elem.find("div.mpcontent");
                             //логика работы
                }

        var methods = { 
          init:function() {},
          close:function() {}

        }

       $.fn.milkpop = function( method, callback1st, callback2nd ) { 
                   //вызываем метод или инициализируем плагин
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Мне нужно, чтобы переменные mpControl и mpContent для конкретного экземпляра были доступны внутри метода Close()

Как правильно это реализовывать? Чтобы метод мог вызываться внутри и снаружи плагина и взаимодействовал со всеми его перменными.

---

**Апдейт**
Из того, что придумал после написания поста.

1. Записать управляющие элементы в `data`, для элемента к которому применяется плагин.
   Дальше внутри метода вытаскивать эти объекты и работать с ними (мне не очень нравится)
2. Записать управляющие объекты в массив `settings`. Передавать его в функцию `Close()`, т.к. он там все равно нужен для выбора скорости и эффекта. Там считывать с него.

   ```
   var settings = $.extend({
   controlEl: elem.find(".mpcontrol"),
   contentEl: elem.find("div.mpcontent")
   }, options || {} );

   methods.close.call(elem, settings);
   ```

Уже все работает, осталось получить уверенность в том, что это правильный подход :)

Comment: > Я перечитал все мануалы, возможные структуры плагинов

@Blackmore а вы не пробовали посмотреть исходный код не обусфицированного JQuery и понять как он работает с плагинами?!

Comment: Не совсем понял, у меня вопрос не в том, как jQuery работает с плагинами, а в том, как наиболее правильно реализовать нужный мне функционал.

Comment: Идея передачи контекста - не самая хорошая, так как в теории - непредсказуема (чего-то где-то может не быть или быть не то).

Лучше, когда всё, что нужно передается как аргумент. Если нужны масштабные изменения передаются две структуры, входная, откуда берем данные, и выходная, В аттрибуты которой пишем.

Comment: @Blackmore, не могли бы вы поделиться ссылками того что прочитали? (для моего собственного развития интересуюсь)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_jQuery

Ну и все по запросу make jquery plugin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее всего использовать jquery [Widget Factory](https://jqueryui.com/widget/). Я тут сделал демонстрационный пример, как создать плагин пользуясь данной методикой, это поможет вам обойти все подводные камни:

http://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/zNVgMK

```
(function($) {
  $.widget("custom.milkpop", {

    // параметры по умолчанию
    options: {
      bgColor: 'red', //цвет фона для ссылки открывающей модалку
      content: 'Hello world!',

      // Callbacks
      beforeShow: null,
      afterShow: null
    },

    // Конструктор
    _create: function() {
      //контекст уже содержит ссылку на jquery объект DOM-элемента
      this.element.css('background-color', this.options.bgColor);

      this._on(this.element, {
        click: "open"
      });
    },

    // public method (начинается без префикса _)
    open: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();

      this._trigger("beforeShow");
      //заглушка, put your code for open modal here
      alert(this.options.content);
      this._trigger("afterShow");
    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```